# ordinalize input-group-addon based on input value in bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Consider the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            Rank: <input class="form-control" name="myrank" id="myrank" type="number" value="1">
        </div>
    </div> <span class="input-group-addon">st</span>

</div>
```

Here I want my Rank to be displayed as 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th & so on. so I would like to update `span.input-group-addon`'s html based on value from `#myrank`. so far I am able to detect the change & get the value like this:

```
function ordinal(n) {
   var s=["th","st","nd","rd"],
       v=n%100;
   return n+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
}


$(function (){
  $('input[type="number"]').on('input', function(e) {
    var rank_ordinal = ordinal(this.value);
    //how do I get to the sibling span from instance of 'this'?
    // something like this $(this).parent().parent().parent().next()?
  });
});
```

Basically, I am looking for a selector to traverse the DOM, so I can get to  `span.input-group-addon` from `this` as page can have multiple inputs, so I want to update value where user made the change. any pointers?

Comment: i cant see `data-role` anywhere in html..

Comment: Fixed the html to remove `data-role` & used the normal input selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that span by,

```
 $('input[type="number"]').on('input', function(e) {
    var rank_ordinal = ordinal(this.value);
    var $span= $(this).closest('div.form-group').next('span.input-group-addon');
  });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6cFjp/)